# How to change access_token on Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to know how to change the duration of an access_token on Snowflake?
By default is 600 seconds.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-security-integration.html

Thank you,
Daniela

Answer (score 0):

You can change the duration of an access_token with the parameter `OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY = <integer>`.

Note: This only works if you set the parameter `OAUTH_ISSUE_REFRESH_TOKENS = TRUE`. With `OAUTH_ISSUE_REFRESH_TOKENS = FALSE` your duration is always 600 seconds and cannot be changed.

Example from docs:

```
create security integration oauth_kp_int
  type=oauth
  enabled=true
  oauth_client = custom
  oauth_client_type='CONFIDENTIAL'
  oauth_redirect_uri='https://localhost.com'
  oauth_issue_refresh_tokens = true
  oauth_refresh_token_validity = 86400
  pre_authorized_roles_list = 'MYROLE'
  blocked_roles_list = ('SYSADMIN')
  oauth_client_rsa_public_key='
  MIIBI
  ..
  ';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is for refresh token not for the access tocken.